# Hitting Error while iterating the row under While loop followed by If Else condition for Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, openpyxl, xlwings

With my current task I am trying to iterate all of my excel rows and then copy each row as a new record to the destination template file. the source file and the destination files are different hence I am assigning the value to the destination cell.

```
# code run sample file
# import os
import pandas as pd
import xlwings as xw
newdir_path = " "
file1 = "list.xlsx"
# read the source file
data = pd.read_excel(file1, sheet_name=0, header=0,
                                 index_col=False, keep_default_na=True)
# creating pandas dataframe from the source file
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Funktion', 'AD65', 'W70', 'B14', 'AC21'])
B14 = ['RR', 'BB', 'RA', 'MM']
booleans = []
# to iterate all the rows
for i in df.itertuples(index=True):
    # only to read the rows where column AD65(2nd column) does not have blank value or none
    while i[AD65] != 'None':
      # to retrieve the row values
      # when B14 value is RR
      if B14 == 'RR':
         print(i)
         # retrieving the values
         Funktion = i.Funktion
         AD65 = i.AD65
         W70 = i.W70
         B14 = i.B14
         AC21 = i.AC21
         booleans.append(True)
         
      # when B14 is B1
      elif B14 == 'BB':
         print(i)
         Funktion = i.Funktion
         AD65 = i.AD65
         W70 = i.W70
         B14 = i.B14
         AC21 = i.AC21
         booleans.append(True)
      
      elif B14 == 'RA':
         # repeating the same as above
         booleans.append(True)
      
      elif B14 == 'MM':
         booleans.append(True)
      else:
    # I want to skip the rows when B14 value is blank
```

Note: I also tried my condition with **if df.loc[['B14'] == 'RR']:** and it is throwing     raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: False

Comment: Remove the `break` from the end of your `for` loop. The `break` statement causes the loop to stop after the first item.

Comment: You're breaking from the loop.

Comment: You are also using `for i in df.itertuples(index=True):` but then never using the tuple for anything other than printing it. You should probably use the values in `i` rather than using all of the `df._get_value(...)` statements.

Comment: That makes total sense thanks a lot for this.

Comment: @Craig that is because my template file is encrypted and I can only pass the values to the cell range as I assigned so I thought that is the best way to do it. And I really don't know how we actually can use the values in i ? Did u mean bypassing as parameters?

Comment: `itertuples()` returns a named tuple as explained in the pandas [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.itertuples.html), so instead of `Funktion = df._get_value(0, 'Funktion')`  you can write `Funktion = i.Funktion`.

Comment: @Craig Thank you so much for the help it works now as expected.                   However, I have one more problem here: I have updated the code above. With While loop it is throwing the error:     while i[AD65] != 'None':
NameError: name 'AD65' is not defined                                                                                     
                                                                                                                                 
And without While loop : my code is not returning anything for my If Elif conditions.